# unexpected keyword argument 'tenant_id' while accessing Azure Key Vault in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-keyvault

I was trying to accessing my key vault, but I got always the same error:

```
AppServiceCredential.get_token failed: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tenant_id'
ManagedIdentityCredential.get_token failed: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tenant_id'
```

This was the code I used in an Azure Machine Learning notebook, copied from the docs:

```py
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

credential = ManagedIdentityCredential()
secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url="https://XXXX.vault.azure.net/", credential=credential)

secretName = 'test'
retrieved_secret = secret_client.get_secret(secretName) # here's the error
retrieved_secret
```

What is wrong? Could you help me?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error is because of a bug that has since been fixed in `azure-identity`'s `ManagedIdentityCredential`. Key Vault clients in recent packages include a tenant ID in token requests to support cross-tenant authentication, but some `azure-identity` credentials didn't correctly handle this keyword argument until the bug was fixed in [version 1.8.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/identity/azure-identity/CHANGELOG.md#180-2022-03-01). Installing `azure-identity`>=1.8.0 should fix the error you're getting.

(Disclaimer: I work for the Azure SDK for Python)

Comment: I am seeing this issue in azure-identity==1.11.0. All of a sudden it appeared. It used to work earlier with the same version. Is there a known issue?

Comment: Multi-tenant authentication was modified in `azure-identity` 1.11.0 ([changelog](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/identity/azure-identity/CHANGELOG.md#1110-2022-09-19)), so that could be the cause of new `ClientAuthenticationError`s. Are you specifically seeing the unexpected keyword argument error, or something else? Also, which Key Vault package/version (or other client package) are you using?

Comment: Thank you for reverting. After some debugging another library is overriding the library version 1.11.0 and setting it as 1.7.0 which is causing the issue. I was able to resolve the issue by figuring out the dependencies.

Comment: can I know which lib overrides the version

Comment: This does not work and should not be the accepted answer. Alex M's answer below works and is reproducible.

Comment: @JohnStud, which package versions did you have installed? Were you still seeing the same unexpected keyword argument error, or something else related to the tenant?

Answer (score 2):

Having the same issue right now (also working with Azure ML Compute Instance), and only downgrading the packages worked for me.

- azure-identity==1.11.0
- azure-keyvault-secrets==4.6.0

@mccoyp: Maybe you can give this feedback to the team

Comment: Confirmed to fix the issue; pretty sloppy that this is still an issue 1.3 years later.

Comment: Hi @Alex M, can you share which package versions were causing you to see this error? And just to confirm, was it the same unexpected keyword argument error?