# How to get specific key vault from azure ml workspace?

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, azure-machine-learning-service

I see lot of documentations which retires the default keyvault. But lets say I have a key vault names, sample_kv, how do i retrieve that in my code?

I couldn't find any sources helpful, please let me know any

#to get deafult keyvault,i used this, but i want to retrieve keyvault by its name

```
keyvault = ws.get_default_keyvault()
```

error

```
DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.Attempted credentials:EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a key vault by its name using the **Azure Key Vault Secrets client library**:

First install [azure-keyvault-secrets](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-secrets/) and [azure-identity](https://pypi.org/project/azure-identity/).

Then you can retrieves a secret stored in the Key Vault using this code:

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential 
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient 
credential = DefaultAzureCredential() 
keyvault_name = "sample_kv" 
secret_name = "my_secret" 
secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=f"https://{keyvault_name}.vault.azure.net/", credential=credential) 
secret_value = secret_client.get_secret(secret_name).value
```

Make sure you have the configuring your environment for the [DefaultAzureCredential](https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/docs#azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredential) for authentication.

For more information you can refer to [Azure Key Vault Secrets client library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/keyvault-secrets-readme?view=azure-python) documentation.

Comment: Hi rishab, i'm getting this error if i use DefaultAzureCredential 
DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
Attempted credentials:
 EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
i'm new to this, can you help me out ?

Comment: Please check this Troubleshooting guide [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/identity/azure-identity/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#troubleshoot-environmentcredential-authentication-issues) for Default Azure credential errors.

Comment: found the answer - for futher guys looking for it in this
[stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72258087/unexpected-keyword-argument-tenant-id-while-accessing-azure-key-vault-in-pytho) 
azure identity version must be >=1.8